# Classifying each variable

Tags: statistics

How can classify variables(number of the company, months, sector and size).

[image]

I Thought...

company = discrete quantitative variable

months (watch below)=

sector = nominal qualitative variable

size = qualitative ordinal variable

Am I right?

Comment: what is the meaning of 'month'? What does month=8 mean for company 1?

Comment: months = months that we have a increase in the activities. Month=8 means that the company 1 increased its activities for 8 months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sector = nominal categorical variable

- nominal because the is no order (trade > trade > industry makes no sense)
- categorical because there are only a finite number of values (you can also call them discrete, it is the same)

size = ordinal categorical variable

- qualitative, because there is an order big > medium > small
- categorical, see above

company = ordinal/nominal categorical variable

- depending on if you want to say an order makes sense, I would tend to 'no' so nominal.

Please note that some of the things you suggested conflict:
  discrete quantitative variable

Note that discrete = categorical and quantitative = continous. But your variable is either discrete (finite number of values) or continous (infinite), it can't be both at the same time.

I skipped month, because of my comment, what does that even mean in this context?

Have a look at this link for more details:
https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/types-of-variable.php

*Update for month:*

From the data you give, I would say month is an ordinal categorical variable. Certainly there is an order 8 > 7 that makes sense. You only gave full numbers, you could also image month = 4.5 in that case it would be continous interval variable.

Comment: months = months that we have an increase in the activities. Month=8 in company 1 means that the company 1 increased its activities during 8 months